# What does the author mean by "no method exists for exactly computing the eigenvalues..."?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" SECTION 5B, he says that: "*Unfortunately no method exists for exactly computing the eigenvalues of
an operator from its matrix.*"

I'm not sure what he means by this. Surely we can find the eigenvalues from the matrix by solving the polynomial equation $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ for $\lambda$, isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: I would say you are right. Maybe he means that it is not always possible to find the roots of the polynomial with pen and paper (as there are no exact methods for degree of order higher than 4)

Comment: How would you exactly solve a polynomial equation of degree say 100?  In practice, iterative methods are used to numerically find approximations to the eigenvalues of matrices.

Comment: In case of dimension five and above, solving the polynomial $\det(A-\lambda I)$ by radicals may be impossible, nor will any other method help finding **exact** solutions algebraically

Comment: It is a discreet tribute to Galois.

Comment: You could have got a clue from the sentence “Powerful numeric techniques exist for finding good approximations to the eigenvalues of an operator from its matrix.” located right to the left of the sentence that you quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an $m \times m$ matrix $A$, the eigenvalue equation you state is an $m$th order polynomial, for which there is no general method for finding roots. However, if $m\in\{1,2,3, 4\} $ successful analytic approaches have been found.

Comment: And $m=4$ as well.

Comment: Edited, thanks for correction

Answer (score 0):

Fact 1: any matrix $A$ has a characteristic polynomial $p_A$; all roots of $p_A$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

Fact 2: Any polynomial $p$ has a matrix $A$ such that $p_A=p$. There is actually a nice explicit construction of this which comes about by looking at the linear ordinary differential equation of order $d$ whose coefficients are exactly the coefficients in $p$, and then rewriting it as a system of $d+1$ first order ODEs. The coefficient matrix of this linear system of ODEs is called the companion matrix for $p$.

Fact 3: The Abel-Ruffini theorem tells you that there is no solution to a general polynomial equation of degree higher than 4 in radicals. In effect to solve such a thing exactly you have to bring in special functions such as the inverse of $x^5+x$.

Fact 1 was really just a warmup: the main point is that Fact 2+Fact 3 means that there cannot be an algorithm for the general eigenvalue problem in dimension above $4$ whose result is an elementary function of the inputs, because if there were then you could use this algorithm on the companion matrix of a certain polynomial and thereby contradict the Abel-Ruffini theorem.